# How to export/link user e-mails?

Tags: parse-platform

So we're using Parse.com's signup, and e-mails of user signups go into the User Class. We're also using MailChimp at the moment for our campaign software. How can we export or link the two so that any e-mails from signups go to our MailChimp lists?

I know that Parse has some Cloud Module integrations with Mandrill and SendGrid, but nothing with MailChimp directly.

Comment: Are you looking to add these user to the MailChimp list after they signup or export an existing list of users to MailChimp?

Comment: @sarvesh Add them automatically to a list as they sign up.

Comment: Looks like someone has already provided a pretty good answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24215165/1922144).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these articles can help you:
https://www.parse.com/questions/mailchimp

Github project: Mailchimp API + Mandrill API optimized for Parse.com Cloud Code
https://github.com/icangowithout/parse-mailchimp/commit/0d75b8be9775347efd939c8715d5d2b13076353c

```
var api_key = "YOUR_MAILCHIMP_API_KEY";

// use https and last verison
var options = {secure: true, version: "1.3"};

// Set the path to the mailchimp module
// If you cloned the mailchimp lib somewhere else, it's time to set this
// value properly
var module_path = "cloud/libs/mailchimp/";

var MailChimpAPI = require(module_path+"MailChimpAPI.js");
var myChimp = new MailChimpAPI(api_key, options, module_path); 
myChimp.ping({}, function(error, data){
    // data is a string or JSON parsed object
    if(error){
        // Oops… there was a problem...
    }else{
        // Do something with the data
    }
    // Handle what to do with the ping
});
//or
// Parse callback style
myChimp.ping({}, {
    success: function(data){
        // data is a string or JSON parsed object
        // Howdy! The ping worked!
    },
    error: function(error){
        // Something went wrong...
    }
});
```